# Segmentation Fault in C doing a concurrent server

Tags: c, server, pthreads

I'm doing a concurrent server and I have a process which function is to join the closed threads. The thing is that I get a segmentation fault at the moment that he checks if a thread is working or not.

Here I initialize the status to 2 that means that still not executed. And I execute the thread

```
for (int i = 0; i < Max_threads; i++){
        clients_data[i].client_number = 0;
        clients_data[i].status = 2;
    }
pthread_create(&tjoins, NULL, (void *(*) (void *))process_joins, (void*)&clients_data);
```

This is the function:

```
void* process_joins(struct clients* data[Max_threads]){     
    while (true){
        for (int i = 0; i < Max_threads; i++){
            if(data[i]->status == 0){
                pthread_join(tclient[data[i]->position], (void**)&data[i]->info);
                data[i]->client_number = 0;
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
```

While doing printf to check where the code breaks, I know it happens at the line:

```
if(data[i]->status==0){
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a difference between a pointer of an array and an array of pointers.

Comment: there are missing parts: where is allocated the clients_data array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have declared `clients_data` as -

```
struct clients clients_data[Max_threads];
```

You are passing `&clients_data` to the function, which is of type - `struct clients (*)[Max_threads]`. But what the function expects is `struct clients* [Max_threads]`. These are both different things.

To fix this you can change the function definition as -

```
void* process_joins(struct clients (*data)[Max_threads]){
    while (true){
        for (int i = 0; i < Max_threads; i++){
            if((*data)[i].status == 0){
                pthread_join(tclient[(*data)[i].position], (void**) &((*data)[i].info));
                (*data)[i].client_number = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But since this function is supposed to expect a `void*`, I would suggest using

```
void *process_joins(void *data_ptr) {
    struct clients (*data)[Max_threads] = data_ptr;
    // Rest of the function same as above
}
```

Now, while this would fix your issue you don't really need a pointer to the array, you can just pass a pointer to the first element as -

```
pthread_create(&tjoins, NULL, (void *(*) (void *))process_joins, (void*)clients_data);
```

and define your function as -

```
void* process_joins(void *clients_data_ptr){
    struct clients *data = clients_data_ptr;
    while (true){
        for (int i = 0; i < Max_threads; i++){
            if((data[i].status == 0){
                pthread_join(tclient[data[i].position], (void**) &(data[i].info));
                data[i].client_number = 0;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It really worked. Can you explain me the difference between (*)clients_data[Max_threads] and *clients_data[Max_threads] ?

Comment: @raultds the first as I said is a pointer to an array of `struct clients` and the second is an array of pointers to `struct clients`. You can see [this](https://cdecl.org/?q=struct+clients+%28*data%29%5B10%5D%3B) and [this](https://cdecl.org/?q=struct+clients+*data%5B10%5D%3B).

Comment: Also, notice the small change I made in the function declaration. It should be `(*data)[Max_threads]` instead of `(*)data[Max_threads]`